# Kudu post-deployment commands not running

Tags: batch-file, azure, kudu

I'm trying to run some scripts after my site is deployed to azure (via kudu)

I have the following directory structure

```
-solution
  - .deployment
  - deploy.cmd 
    - deployment
       - postdeployactions
         - test.bat
```

.deployment looks like this:

```
[config]
POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION_DIR  = deployment\postdeployactions\
command = deploy.cmd
```

deploy.cmd is unmodified from the one generated by `azure site deploymentscript --aspWAP pathToYourWebProjectFile.csproj -s pathToYourSolutionFile.sln` (http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38418009331/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart2/#.VPYd_PmUeTI)

However test.bat is not getting called.

I have tried setting both POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION_DIR and SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH (see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1154)

Comment: @AAlferez not using the .deployment file sadly, afaik it doesnt do anything. This setting does work if you add it as an appsetting in azure though

Comment: I actually did add the file .deployment to my root repo and it gets executed!
POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION_DIR = site\deployments\tools\PostDeploymentActions

Comment: @LukeMcGregor: **Which setting did you set** in your app settings? The `SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH` or the `POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION_DIR`? I have the first one and it used to run my custom batch file in the folder configured, but for some reason this stopped working about 2 months ago or so and I haven't changed anything about files/settings that could impact non-execution? **And which folder path** did you include? from `home\site\repository\...` or or from `site\repository\...` or... What's root for this setting?

Answer (score 2):

Some "Site Extensions" reconfigure this behaviour inside Azure.

For example, if you use Composer Site Extension in a PHP Web Site, 
default kudu deployment script is replaced by other script injected by Composer Site Extension.

Maybe this could be your case.

Look at your COMMAND environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly the same thing but instead of POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION_DIR I use SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH, could that be the issue?

```
[config]
SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH = deployment\postdeployactions\
```